# Re-rendering conditional buttons

Tags: reactjs, button, state, conditional-rendering

This is for an interactive bible.

In the following code I have buttons that are being conditionally rendered based upon the buttons I previously clicked.

The code calls an API to retrieve the data.

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchBibleBooks());
        }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(selectedBook && chapter){
            dispatch(fetchBibleBookChapter( {selectedBook, chapter} ));
        }
    }, [dispatch, selectedBook, chapter]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setOTBooks(bibleArray.filter(book => book.testament === 'OT'));
    }, [ clickedOT ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setNTBooks(bibleArray.filter(book => book.testament === 'NT'));        
    }, [ clickedNT ]);  

    useEffect(() => {
        setBookChapters(bibleArray.find(book => book.id === selectedBook)?.chapters || []);
    }, [ selectedBook ]);

    useEffect(() => { 
       bibleArray.filter(chapter => chapter);
       const subsetBibleArray = bibleArray.map( text => text.cleanText ); 
       setChapterText(subsetBibleArray);
       
    });

    return(
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <h1 style={{ color: 'darkblue'}}>Biblia Interactiva</h1>
                    <Button style={{margin: '2rem'}} color='warning' size='lg' onClick={() => setClickedOT(true)}>
                        Antiguo Testamento
                    </Button>{' '}
                    <Button style={{margin: '2rem'}} color='warning' size='lg' onClick={() => setClickedNT(true)}>
                        Nuevo Testamento
                    </Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row style={{marginTop:'4rem'}}>
                <Col style={{textAlign:'left', marginLeft:'-18rem'}}>
                    {
                         clickedOT && otBooks.sort((b1, b2) => {
                                    if (b1.order < b2.order) return -1;
                                    if (b1.order > b2.order) return 1;
                                    return 0;
                                }).map(book => (
                                    <Button color='primary' key={book.order} style={{ margin: '4px' }} onClick={() => setSelectedBook(book.id)}>
                                        {book.name}
                                    </Button> 
                            ))
                        }
                </Col>
                <Col style={{textAlign:'left', marginRight:'-18rem'}}>
                    {
                        clickedNT && ntBooks.sort((b1, b2) => {
                                    if (b1.order < b2.order) return -1;
                                    if (b1.order > b2.order) return 1;
                                    return 0;
                                }).map(book => (
                                    <Button color='primary' key={book.order} style={{ margin: '4px' }} onClick={() => setSelectedBook(book.id)}>
                                        {book.name}
                                    </Button>
                            ))}
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col style={{textAlign:'center', marginLeft:'', marginTop: '6rem'}}>
                        {
                            bookChapters.map(ch => (
                                    <Button color='success' key={ch.id} style={{ margin: '4px' }} onClick={() => setChapter(ch.chapter)}>
                                        {ch.chapter}
                                    </Button>
                                )
                            )
                        }
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col style={{textAlign:'left', marginLeft:'', marginTop: '6rem'}}>
                        {
                            chapterText.map((text, idx) => (
                                    <p key={idx}>
                                        {text}
                                    </p>
                                )
                            )
                        }
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

The code work well the first go around but if I re-click one of the Bible book buttons, the previously rendered chapter buttons will disappear and so will the text, which is fine but it should re-render the chapter buttons to the new relevant book clicked.

The 'selectedBook' variable is updated but the state variable 'chapter' is still holding the value of the previous chapter and so the new state has the new book with the old chapter and fetches that chapter from the API and the relevant chapter buttons don't get rendered.

Comment: This code could really benefit from [You might not need an effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect). Specifically, see this part: `You don’t need Effects to handle user events`. In short - don't do things in effects (which might "work" but makes it incredibly hard to read for anybody but the author), just do them directly in the event handlers. While I'm sure your code could be "fixed" in it's current form, it'd be a great exercise to re-write it to clearly understand the data flow.

Comment: Thank you Brian.  I actually fixed it.  It seems that the issue was with how I was updating state.  I make two calls to the API.  That's fine.  The issue was that I was updating the same state array, bibleArray, from the two different API calls.  

So the second time I made the call to the API, I was overwriting my previous state.bible.bibleArray.  

What I did was I added a second array, newBibleArray, in my bibleSlice.js in redux so that I can update state.bible.newBibleArray, using the data from the first API call in state.bible.bibleArray and finally displaying the text.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Reset selectedBookChapter whenever a new book is chosen in the event handler (not in an effect)

```
const onChangeBook = (id) => {
   setSelectedBook(book.id);
   setSelectedChapter(undefined); // undefined, or null, or similar
}
```

and then have all your buttons call this function

2. There's no "bookChapters" state - `bookChapters` is computed/derived as a consequence of a book being selected (or not), but it's not state itself.

```
const bookChapters = bibleArray.find(book => book.id === selectedBook)?.chapters || []
```

That's it. It gets recomputed on every render and that's fine (unless you have a performance issue). You don't need state to to hold `bookChapters`.

It's unlikely that `chapterText` is state as well, it shouldn't be state and the effect shouldn't exist.

See this [You might not need an effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)

Comment: Thank you Adam. 

It seems that the issue was with how I was updating state.  I make two calls to the API.  That's fine.  The issue was that I was updating the same state array, state.bible.bibleArray, from the two different API calls.  

So the second time I made the call to the API, I was overwriting my previous state.bible.bibleArray.  

What I did was I added a second array, newBibleArray, to my initialState in my bibleSlice.js in redux so that I can update state.bible.newBibleArray, using the data from the first API call in state.bible.bibleArray and finally displaying the text.

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it.

It seems that the issue was with how I was updating state.

I make two calls to the API. That's fine. The issue was that I was updating the same state, state.bible.bibleArray, from the two different API calls.

So the second time I made the call to the API, I was overwriting my previous state.bible.bibleArray. What I did was I added a second array, newBibleArray, in the initialState in my bibleSlice.js in redux so that I can update state.bible.newBibleArray, using the data from the first API call in state.bible.bibleArray and finally displaying the text.